Marketplace submissions stuck for months now
I develop an extension available in Adobe Commerce marketplace for almost a year now.
I've sent numerous updates for this extension, and the validation process was quite quick, with in general 2 or 3 days of delay for the validation to be made by Adobe teams.
Since around 4 months now, all my submissions for updates are stuck in the status "In progress", and I have no informations whatsoever about why.
Is there any problems on the validation process? Is it just my extension, or more developers experience the same delays?
I've not found any informations on the matter on the numerous Adobe documentations or forums available, or in Stack Exchange and related websites. Am I missing something?
Thanks for you help!
Simon

Ok, it seems that everybody is experiencing the same issue. I keep the question open for fellows developers who struggle with this issue.
It seems to me that there is a great lack of communication from Adobe on the matter.

They have very slow process currently.

Thanks for your comment. Do you happened to know if they communicate about that, and how? Is there any way to have an alert when the situation will be back to normal?

Either contact on there support by email or contact on there slack channel.

Nevermind, the problem was on my side.
For everyone experiencing the same issue, you may find useful to check the test results of the version pending validation.
In my case, there was an issue in the dependency of my extension. But, contrary to the previous behaviour, I was not notified of the test failure.

